# How to get a nested object in JSON in Kotlin?

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin, nested

I've created the classes of Eqs and Service, got the service objects but can't get the list of eqs. Can anyone help me with this?
This the Eqs class

```
 data class Eqs(
  val name: String,
  val imageUrl: String,
  val description: String?,
  val responsible: String
)
```

That's the Service class which gets its values

```
data class Service(
  val title: String,
  val servings: Int,
  val eqs: List<Eqs>
    )  {

  companion object {

    fun getServicesFromFile(filename: String, context: Context): ArrayList<Service> {
      val serviceList = ArrayList<Service>()

      try {
        // Load data
        val jsonString = loadJsonFromAsset("services.json", context)
        val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
        val services = json.getJSONArray("services")


        (0 until services.length()).mapTo(serviceList) {
          Service(services.getJSONObject(it).getString("title"),
              services.getJSONObject(it).getInt("servings"),
        }
      } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
      }

      return serviceList
    }
```

I can't get the List of Eqs in my getServicesFromFile function. How to parse and get it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use `Jackson` library. It's simple and saves you a lot of time. You can find it's documentation here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-kotlin

You also can use some websites to generate the data class needed for `Jackson` like https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Json to Kotlin plugin
2. In tool bar of android studio Code >> Generate and copy & paste you API into it and give the class name

> ```
>     [
>         {
>             "id": 1,
>             "name" : "Madoldoowa",
>             "description": "Madol Doova (මඩොල් දූව) is a children's novel and coming-of-age story written by Sri Lankan writer
> ```
>
> Martin Wickramasinghe and first published in 1947",
>                   "language" : "Sinhala",
>                   "isbn" : "ISBN232673434",
>                   "file_size" : 300,
>                   "no_of_pages" : 500,
>                   "price" : 970,
>                   "ratings" : "5.1K",
>                   "cover_page" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/MadolDoova.jpg",
>                   "author" :  {
>                           "name" : "Martin Wickramasinghe"
>                               }
>               ]
>
> ```
> data class Model(
>     val author: Author,
>     val cover_page: String,
>     val description: String,
>     val file_size: Int,
>     val id: Int,
>     val isbn: String,
>     val language: String,
>     val name: String,
>     val no_of_pages: Int,
>     val price: Int,
>     val ratings: String
> )
>
> data class Author(
>     val name: String
> )
> ```